# JMeter WebDriver Sampler Groovy : Error unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager is thrown

Tags: macos, selenium, jmeter

I have `JMeter 5.5` running on Mac `12.6 (21G115)` with WebDriver Sampler for doing client side performance testing. It works without any issue with `javascript`.

[image]

I want to move to Groovy quickly and got following error when test was executed.
It looks like a PATH issue.

```
2023-01-04 23:14:08,307 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/manager/SeleniumManager
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:41) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at
```

Following Selenium jars are available in `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext` folder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JavaDoc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/manager/SeleniumManager.html)

> This implementation is still in beta, and may change. The Selenium-Manager binaries are distributed in a JAR file (org.openqa.selenium:selenium-manager) for the Java binding language

I fail to see any sign of `selenium-manager` jar in your beautiful screenshot hence you're getting the error.

If you want to instantiate the WebDriver yourself - move to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and make sure that selenium-manager is in your classpath.

ChromeDriver is being managed by [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) so you can just add it, provide the path to your [`chromedriver` executable](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and refer it in your script as `WDS.browser`

[image]

The above code should work just fine assuming you've installed WebDriver Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Also "lib/ext" folder is for JMeter Plugins, dependency libraries should go "lib" folder, see [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) section for more details.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri. It was possible to resolve the issue after placing the [Selenium manager](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/common/manager) Jar file. But two browser instances were started when I used my sample code given in the question. Also following error was in the log `c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: unknown protocol: data`. Also it was noted that the code didn't work without the [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) element.